# How can I configure global settings for default shell for Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, settings

I started to learn Scrapy but I stuck up at weird point where I couldn't set default shell to ipython. The operating system of my laptop is Ubuntu 15.10. I also installed ipython and scrapy. They run well without causing any errors.

According to Scrapy's [official tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html), I can change my default scrapy shell by entering this in the global configuration file

```
 [settings]
 shell = ipython
```

The problem is I couldn't locate the configuration file. I tried following instructions from [another page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#topics-config-settings).

I made these three config files  in

1. `/etc/scrapy.cfg`  (system-wide),
2. `~/.config/scrapy.cfg` ($XDG_CONFIG_HOME) and `~/.scrapy.cfg` ($HOME) for global (user-wide) settings.

but It didn't help at all.

what should I do?

---

I followed the instruction in the first answer by paul trmbrth. There still seems to be a problem though. [image]

seems like I do have a right configuration file in the right place. But I still cannot open scrapy shell with ipython, as you can see in the screenshot. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to configure (or test) the shell used by `scrapy shell` is the [`SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL` environment variable](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#configuring-the-shell).

So running:

```
paul@paul:~$ SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL=ipython scrapy shell
```

would use `ipython` as first choice, whatever setting in `*scrapy.cfg` you may have.

To check where scrapy is looking for config files, and what it finds, you can start the `python` interpreter and run [what `scrapy shell` does](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/shell.py#L67):

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from scrapy.utils.conf import get_config, get_sources
>>> get_sources()
['/etc/scrapy.cfg', 'c:\\scrapy\\scrapy.cfg', '/home/paul/.config/scrapy.cfg', '/home/paul/.scrapy.cfg', '']

>>> cfg = get_config()
>>> cfg.sections()
['deploy', 'settings']
>>> cfg.options('settings')
['shell']
>>> cfg.get('settings', 'shell')
'bpython'
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful and I appreciate that. I still could not open scrapy shell with ipython though.

Comment: anything special printed on the console when you run `ipython`? can you try installing `bpython` and test with `shell = bpython`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside of the project you can use this:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()

settings.get('IMPORT_API_URL')
```

If you are outside of the project, you can use this:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings

settings = Settings()

settings_module_path = os.environ.get('SCRAPY_ENV', 'project.settings.dev')   
settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')

settings.get('BASE_URL')
```